# Interpreting node.js profile output?

Tags: javascript, node.js, debugging, profiling

test.js

```
function test(){
    for(var i=0; i<2000000000; ++i);
};
test();
```

Commands used to profile it:

```
node --prof test.js
nprof
```

Output:

```
line 249: unknown code state: undefined
line 252: unknown code state: undefined
line 253: unknown code state: undefined
line 256: unknown code state: undefined
line 258: unknown code state: undefined
line 259: unknown code state: undefined
line 260: unknown code state: undefined
line 261: unknown code state: undefined
line 262: unknown code state: undefined
line 263: unknown code state: undefined
line 264: unknown code state: undefined
line 265: unknown code state: undefined
line 266: unknown code state: undefined
(This repeats around 1000 times. I'm removing it from this paste...)

 [Unknown]:
   ticks  total  nonlib   name
     34   79.1%

 [Shared libraries]:
   ticks  total  nonlib   name
      8   18.6%    0.0%  /usr/local/bin/node
      1    2.3%    0.0%  /usr/lib/system/libsystem_kernel.dylib

 [JavaScript]:
   ticks  total  nonlib   name

 [C++]:
   ticks  total  nonlib   name

 [GC]:
   ticks  total  nonlib   name
      0    0.0%

 [Bottom up (heavy) profile]:
  Note: percentage shows a share of a particular caller in the total
  amount of its parent calls.
  Callers occupying less than 2.0% are not shown.

   ticks parent  name
      8   18.6%  /usr/local/bin/node

      1    2.3%  /usr/lib/system/libsystem_kernel.dylib
```

I was expecting it to show the "test" function on the [JavaScript] part. Why it's not there?

Comment: What version of node?  Using 0.8.2 (for example) I use your program and get output that I'd expect, and nothing like what I see in your post.  My output is here: http://pastebin.com/embed_js.php?i=mztwZLfd

Comment: @Joe, 0.8.2 that I just built on OSX. Weird.

Answer (score 2):

nprof uses tick processor for v8.log format different from what you have

I'm having the same [issue](https://github.com/sidorares/node-tick/pull/3) in [node-tick](https://github.com/sidorares/node-tick) ( which is currently compatible with node 0.8.2 afaik ).

Possible solutions:

- try [node-tick](https://github.com/sidorares/node-tick)
- try previous version of nprof ( `npm install profiler@1.2.0` )

or you can try to rebuild nprof with scripts from your node version:

```
  git clone https://github.com/bnoordhuis/node-profile
  git clone https://github.com/joyent/node
  cd node
  git checkout v0.8.7-release # can't see tag for 0.8.2
  cp deps/v8/tools/*.js ../node-profile/tools/v8
  cd ../node-profile
  sh tools/build-nprof
```